# How to add or route PostgreSQL Data to New Hard Drive

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Im Using Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Im Running PostgreSQL 9.0.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit

I got C:/ and D:/ Drive

C:/ --> 6.7GB free space (almost full and my server performance running low)

D:/ --> 141GB free space

Currently my PostgreSQL Data stored at C:/ Now,I want to route or add path to D:/ without migrate the data from C:/ to D:/ because now my PostgreSQL Data Stored around 148 GB. It Heavy and Massive Stored.

If success, I should still be able to do a query like `SELECT * From table_bla_bla` and it will return result from both drives?

Please do not suggest me to change PostgreSQL to other DB or whatsoever. 
Because Im running 39,763 Device GPS Meter that send the data to my Server.

I have to take care this server because my expert already past-away.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve: do you want to _move_ all data from C: to D:?  Or only store new data on D? Or only move certain tables to the D drive? You can't distribute the data of a single table over multiple drives

Comment: My C:/ already full. and I want to store in D:/ without migrate the data from C:/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use tablespaces.

1. Create the tablespace, for example `CREATE TABLESPACE second_drive LOCATION 'D:/postgresdata/'` (see [this other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83041/how-to-create-a-tablespace-on-windows-7-for-postgresql-9-2) if you get permission denied errors)
2. `ALTER TABLE table_bla_bla SET tablespace second_drive`

Tablespaces allow you to decide which tables go on which drives and that can help speed up performance by ensuring you control where reads and writes go, but it also helps with space.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres places individual tables in TABLESPACEs (which relate to a single disk), which is enough if you have multiple tables and you can achieve what you need by moving some tables to the other disk.

On the other hand, if you have a large table that you need to split over multiple disks, you need to use Postgres's Horizontal Partitioning capability.

This builds on tablespaces by allowing you to create a master table `table_bla_bla` which is actually just a facade on top of two or more tables which actually hold the data.   These data tables can then be put on different tablesspaces effectively splitting your data over disks.

For this you would:

1. Rename your current `table_bla_bla` to something like
   `table_bla_bla_c`
2. Create a new `table_bla_bla` master table.
3. Alter `table_bla_bla_c` to mark that it inherits from
   `table_bla_bla`
4. Create a new `table_bla_bla_d` table that inherits from `table_bla_bla` and specify the tablespace as the D drive.
5. Apply partitioning triggers and check constraints as per the [partitioning documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)

Once this is in place, you can arrange it so that any inserts into `table_bla_bla` cause new records to be created on the D drive.  Selects on `table_bla_bla` will read from both disks.